# how to combine two python functions with the same arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have two functions that do different things and I want to find out what the best practice is for having two functions with the same argumets so that I do not have to give both of the functions the arguments, aka remove redundancy.
The case where I have this is the following:

```
def isBroken(time : np.ndarray, tol:float = 3):

    finiteDifference = np.diff(time)
    broken = np.any(finiteDifference >= tol)
    
    return broken

def brokenLocation(time : np.ndarray, tol:float  = 3):
    
    finiteDifference = np.diff(time)
    brokenWhere = np.argwhere(finiteDifference >= tol)
    brokenStack = np.hstack((brokenWhere,brokenWhere+1))
    
    return brokenStack
```

This code checks isBroken if there is a break in an array larger than a certain tolerance and then brokenLocation gives the location at which it is broken. This is then used in this code:

```
Time = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,13,14,15,16,17,24,25,26,27])

if isBroken(Time):
    
    brokenTuples = brokenLocation(Time)#Technically not tuples

    #do something with Tuples
```

This part is only added for clarity in what way these functions are supposed to be used.

What I want to know is the best practice to remove such a redundancy?

Hopefully someone can help me here.

Comment: The code as written doesn't actually work, because you're not doing anything with the return value of `isBroken`.  When you do `if isBroken`, `isBroken` is the function itself, not the result of calling it.  That said, I don't see any redundancy here -- these functions do two different things, you're doing two different things with the results (at least in theory), and it's not like you're re-building the input array each time.

Comment: If `isBroken(Time)` is `False`, `brokenLocation(Time)` will return an empty list, which is falsy. That way, `isBroken` is kind of redundant.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for catching the copy error i will edit this